# Raphael line graph animate and update graph

Tags: javascript, graph, raphael, graphael

im new to the raphael library so im still learning my way around it, i was able to setup my graph the way i want it, but now im trying to do the following 2 things but im having dificulty finding docs / examples for what i want.

here is what i have so far
http://jsfiddle.net/PA67H/

1. animate the inital data points when the graph loads with something similar to [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/)
2. animate a change in data points, so when the button is pressed the data source is changed to var2 but in an animated way like [here](http://raphaeljs.com/chart.html)

Comment: It's a shame Raphael's graphing arm isn't as well documented as the core library -- I just took a gander at the source code and it is quite opaque =(

Comment: agreed, any suggestions?

Comment: it is possible with Rapheal

Comment: best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.animation

may be you can find out what you wanted.